# What does this artist's name mean? 光収容の倉庫

Tags: meaning, word-requests

I've tried breaking it down as much as I can, and combining it in different ways but I can't seem to find a decent English translation for this guy.

> 光収容の倉庫 
>  *hikari shuuyou* no souko

I italicize the first part of his full artist name because の倉庫 is often dropped, even in some of his album covers. Moreover, I don't think an English version of his name has ever been used on YouTube, Nicovideo, or elsewhere. Most any reference will say "Hikari", "Hikari Syuyo", "Hikari Shuyo", "Hikari Shuuyo", "Hikari Shuuyou", ... (you get the point).

So let me demonstrate what I've tried so far:

> 光 (light) 
>     収容 (accommodation; reception; housing) 
>     倉庫 (storehouse; warehouse; godown) 
>     (many thanks to [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%85%89%E5%8F%8E%E5%AE%B9%E3%81%AE%E5%80%89%E5%BA%AB))

Which I interpret could be a few of the following:

> *Warehouse of Light* (irks me because it ignores 収容) 
>     *Light Storage Warehouse* (awkward and makes "light" seem like an adjective) 
>     *Lighthouse's Storehouse* (doesn't technically mean "lighthouse")

I feel like I'm close to what it means, but I'm really struggling to find the right words to properly translate this to English. Could someone who's more native to Japanese help me out? Thank you!

Comment: If it is a name, then why do want something other than "Hikari", "Hikari Syuyo", "Hikari Shuyo", "Hikari Shuuyo", "Hikari Shuuyou" ...

Comment: That's a fair question. Lots of artist names can be things that don't particularly mean anything more than what they sound like. Others have meanings, and use legitimate words in them. This seems like it would be one that means something, so I'm trying to decipher it. (As an extra reason, when it comes to speaking about music with friends, referencing an artist without switching languages is a huge nicety.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since 光収容の倉庫 is a proper noun, it should not be "translated". If you just want to understand what it means, please read on.

- 光収容 is a technical term, which is explained in [this Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%89%E5%8F%8E%E5%AE%B9). 光収容 basically refers to "bundling" multiple slow and legacy connections using optic fibers. 光 in this context is actually 光ファイバー (optic fiber).
- 倉庫 is just "storehouse".

According to [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%89%E5%8F%8E%E5%AE%B9_(%E9%9F%B3%E6%A5%BD%E5%AE%B6)), 光収容の倉庫 was named as such simply because his internet connection was using 光収容. (So apparently 倉庫 figuratively refers to his home/room.) In other words, his apartment building was not [FTTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_to_the_x)-ready.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a bunch more sense now. No worries, I wasn't really trying to "translate" it. I was just missing the technical term, which I'm actually familiar with.